# Joomla 4 MySQL Not Fully Initialized Issue

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am getting this error when trying to run my Joomla site:

```
Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I just moved a Joomla 4 site from one VPS to this new one.
The old MySQL version was 5.7.
The new version is 8.0.
Also on my last VPS PHP was version 8.0.
The new version is 8.1.

I created a database in the new VPS and logged in through putty/console and installed the database through mysql SOURCE.

That cause the above problem, so I tried importing the database through phpMyAdmin. There were no issues with the import.

The top of the webpage also read:

```
mysqli object is not fully initialized
```

I am not sure what I am missing. I also installed a letsencryps ssl but that doesn't seem to be working either.

END NOTE: I just tried with the `root` user and the site works fine. So its the `GRANT` permission that stops the site opening when using a `testuser`. Any ideas how to get around that or give the `testuser` full `GRANT` permissions?

Some of the errors that are also produced:

```
Error:
mysqli object is not fully initialized

  at /var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php:137
  at mysqli->prepare()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php:137)
  at Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliStatement->__construct()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliDriver.php:1089)
  at Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliDriver->prepareStatement()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/DatabaseDriver.php:1900)
  at Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver->setQuery()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Menu/SiteMenu.php:166)
  at Joomla\CMS\Menu\SiteMenu->Joomla\CMS\Menu\{closure}()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Cache/Controller/CallbackController.php:51)
  at Joomla\CMS\Cache\Controller\CallbackController->get()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Menu/SiteMenu.php:179)
  at Joomla\CMS\Menu\SiteMenu->load()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Menu/AbstractMenu.php:333)
  at Joomla\CMS\Menu\AbstractMenu->getMenu()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Menu/AbstractMenu.php:164)
  at Joomla\CMS\Menu\AbstractMenu->getItem()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:422)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->getTemplate()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Error/Renderer/HtmlRenderer.php:50)
  at Joomla\CMS\Error\Renderer\HtmlRenderer->render()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Exception/ExceptionHandler.php:121)
  at Joomla\CMS\Exception\ExceptionHandler::render()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Exception/ExceptionHandler.php:72)
  at Joomla\CMS\Exception\ExceptionHandler::handleException()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:322)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/includes/app.php:61)
  at require_once('/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/includes/app.php')
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/index.php:32)    
            
[1/2] mysqli_sql_exception
mysqli_sql_exception:
Access denied for user 'TheDrumCoach'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

  at /var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliDriver.php:310
  at mysqli->real_connect()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliDriver.php:310)
  at Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliDriver->connect()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/session/src/Handler/DatabaseHandler.php:233)
  at Joomla\Session\Handler\DatabaseHandler->open()
  at session_start()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/session/src/Storage/NativeStorage.php:478)
  at Joomla\Session\Storage\NativeStorage->start()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Session/Storage/JoomlaStorage.php:295)
  at Joomla\CMS\Session\Storage\JoomlaStorage->start()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/session/src/Session.php:406)
  at Joomla\Session\Session->start()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/vendor/joomla/session/src/Session.php:333)
  at Joomla\Session\Session->has()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Session/Session.php:194)
  at Joomla\CMS\Session\Session->get()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Factory.php:374)
  at Joomla\CMS\Factory::getUser()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:562)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->initialiseApp()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php:226)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293)
  at Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/includes/app.php:61)
  at require_once('/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/includes/app.php')
     (/var/www/public_html/mywebsitedomain.com/index.php:32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have `testuser` operate with the same level of permissions as `root`, then you can do this from inside MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `joomladb`.* TO `testuser`@`localhost`
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `joomladb` with the actual name of the database.</sup>

Your error log shows a different account name failing so, if multiple accounts need full access to this database, be sure to run it once for each account.

Comment: Thanks, That worked. But I believe I ttried that previously. I must have gotten the password smixed up because I also changed the password and it now works fine. Thanks.